# MySQL Grouping Order

Tags: mysql, order-by, group-by

Is it possible to force the order in which a result set is grouped? I have a table with multiple languages in it, and I'm doing a GROUP_CONCAT to get a comma separated list of the product name in each language, for each product_id. However it doesn't seem possible to get MySQL to return that concatenated string in any particular order of language_id's. What I'd like is to be able to order the grouping by language id, so that they'll always come out in a pre-determined order.

Is this possible? If so, how? If not possible within the SELECT statement, is there a modification I can make to the table to adjust how the GROUP BY would order the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY` inside `GROUP_CONCAT()` function. You can also change the separator, if you don't want to use comma. Further details in MySQL documentation: [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Example:

```
SELECT 
    product_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(name 
                 ORDER BY language_id
                 SEPARATOR ','
                ) AS product_names
FROM
    products_languages
GROUP BY
    product_id ;
```

Comment: Note that GROUP_CONCAT has a limit of 1024 bytes. In latin1 encoding that means the return string should have 1024 chars    in utf8 encoding you need to divide by three (1024/3) = 341 chars. You can use SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;  so it can have more chars.